# Better way to implement adsense with other networks in Google DFP

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, google-dfp

I am new to Google DoubleClick. I am in the process of implementing Adsense along with other third party ad networks. The mode of competition is price priority. So an ad network that offers highest CPM will win.

My problem arises when I want to include Adsense in the competition. I can see two ways to achieve that in DFP.

1. I can add a separate order and line item for Adsense. In this case, I will **disable** `Maximize revenue of unsold and remnant inventory with AdSense` option in line item settings of all third party line items.
2. Instead of adding Adsense as a separate line item, I can **enable** `Maximize revenue of unsold and remnant inventory with AdSense` in all third party line items.

Which of the above two ways is the right approach?